# Conversion of Binary into a Negative Integer

Tags: c++, binary, integer, twos-complement, negative-number

Let's hypothetically say that I have a collection of bits that I want to convert into an `int`, but the bits may represent a negative 2's complement number, so for example:

```
vector<bool> foo = { true, false, false, false, false, true, false, false }
```

Obviously if `foo.front()` is set then the number is negative. What would be the best way to convert this to an `int`?

---

This question seems to lack clarity. For reference I've added my brute force solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50108264/2642059 I want to accomplish this same thing but ideally with some provided functionality and not so much hackery.

Comment: Do you have to use a `vector<bool>`?  `std::bitset` should handle this for you.

Comment: You can get the `unsigned int` value and then: `int signed_val = *((int *)&your_unsigned_int);`

Comment: @NathanOliver I can't use `bitset` because I don't know how many bits I'll have at design time, just that there will be less than 32.

Comment: So if you are provided only 12 bits the 12th bit would be the sign bit?

Comment: @NathanOliver Correct, if `foo.front()` is set the number is negative.

Comment: @atmostmediocre Shifting `foo` into an `unsigned int` and just casting to an `int*` doesn't work: https://ideone.com/xqYrzg Unless you are suggesting setting the leading bits in which case it's unclear why I wouldn't have just used an `int` in the first place.

Comment: Did you want to write 0b10001110 ? It is valid since c++14: http://codexpert.ro/blog/2015/04/30/binary-literals-and-digit-separators/

Comment: @Red.Wave I just want to get `foo` into an `int` writing a literal number doesn't seem to help me do that... However if you can show me how this helps... then yes I want to do that.

Comment: If it has to be vector and not bitset, I need ask about the details; how many bits long is your integer value supposed to be?

Comment: @Red.Wave I don't know, I only know that it will be less than 32. So clearly since I don't know I can't use a `bitset`

Comment: Short answer is "extend the sign". But you must take care of a leading 1 and followed by all 0s; it won't be 0, but rather negative of a power of 2.

Comment: @Red.Wave Sounds like there isn't an easier way to do this than the brute force method that I have put forward.

Comment: @JonathanMee if it fits in 64 bits you can check my answer down the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::vector<bool> foo;
//...
long long val=0;
for(auto& bit:foo){
    val<<=1;
    val+=bit;
};

if(foo.front())//sign extension
    val+=~0ll<<foo.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

In two's complement notation, the negative of a number is the complement plus 1.

When `foo.first() == true`, convert all the remaining elements to binary digits, then invert it and add 1. Then return the negative of this.

So in your example, the remaining elements correspond to the binary number `0000000`. Complement this to `1111111`, which is `127`. Add `1` and you get `128`, and then you return `-128`. And indeed, the value `-128` is represented as `10000000` in 8-bit two's complement.

The signed data type you use for this process needs to be at least 1 bit larger than the size of the vector, to avoid overflowing when you add 1 to "all bits set" value. So if your vector can be up to 32 elements (including the sign), you need to use `int64_t`.

Comment: The bits are already in 2's complement. But it looks like your statement is that I should be setting all leading bits...

Comment: It's already in 2's complement, but the vector size is smaller than the bit size of the C++ variable.

Answer (score 0):

The leading set bits for a number, including the bit that should be set for `foo.front()`, can be generated by doing: `-(1 << size(foo) - 1)`. After this you need only shift in the remainder of your bits.

This for example will generate the correct number whether or not `foo.front()` is set:

```
int i = size(foo) - 1;
const auto bar = accumulate(next(cbegin(foo)), cend(foo), foo.front() ? -(1 << i) : 0, [&](const auto val, const auto it) { return val + (it << --i); });
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/YvdCKp)